# How to create table with today calendar ? jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, calendar

HTML

```
<table class="" id="schedule">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input value="Time" type="text"></th>
                <th><input value="Monday" type="text"></th>
                <th><input value="Tuesday" type="text"></th>
                <th><input value="Wednesday" type="text"></th>
                <th><input value="Thursday" type="text"></th>
                <th><input value="Friday" type="text"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><input value="9:00am" type="text"></th>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
                <td class=""></td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
```

my question is how can i generate table with todays hours dynamically without having to hardcoded it in html ?
i need this table to include a tr for each hr of the day (24hr).

My aim : i'm creating a booking page for my clinic website, i have all visits to that clinic stored in mysql as "visit,name_patient,date,time,clinic_num",

i fetch all records for today from db and i want to display it in a table.

**Question**

1. so can some one tell me what is the simplest logic flow to generate
   such a table ?
2. how to generate rows with today's hrs "9am,10am,11am"

**Note:** http://apps.zarjay.net/scheduler/ this looks like what i want but still time is hard coded. most other calendar plugins are really complex and over kill for wt i want

```
etc ?
```

Comment: Even if you hardcoded this I can't think of day with less than 24 hours, all that would need to be dynamic is a date input surely

Comment: Just use JQuery UI. They've already invented that wheel. http://jqueryui.com

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to do it that I'm aware of:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach (range(0, 23) as $i) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo date('ha', mktime($i, 0)); ?></td>
        <td>What ever you want here</td>
    </tr>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Change the values for the `range(0,23)` to suit your needs

Here it is applied to your HTML:

```
<table class="" id="schedule">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input value="Time" type="text"></th>
            <th><input value="Monday" type="text"></th>
            <th><input value="Tuesday" type="text"></th>
            <th><input value="Wednesday" type="text"></th>
            <th><input value="Thursday" type="text"></th>
            <th><input value="Friday" type="text"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach (range(0, 23) as $i) : ?>
        <tr>
            <th><input value="<?php echo date('ha', mktime($i, 0)); ?>" type="text" /></th>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```